# want to upload a image with form in mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, multer

there a database file on mongodb atlas called food_items i want from the frontend form to upload image an data there

Error saving food item: TypeError: global.food_items is not a constructor
at uploadFoodItem (D:\ecom2 - Copy\backend\Routes\AddItem.js:31:25)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\ecom2 - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\ecom2 - Copy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at done (D:\ecom2 - Copy\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:45:7)
at indicateDone (D:\ecom2 - Copy\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:49:68)

```
// imports at the top
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
// const Food = require("../db");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
// Multer configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: (req, file, cb) => {
   const uploadPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads');
   if (fs.existsSync(uploadPath)) {
     cb(null, uploadPath);
   } else {
     console.error('Upload path does not exist or is not accessible');
     cb(new Error('Upload path does not exist or is not accessible'));
   }
 },
 filename: (req, file, cb) => {
   const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
   const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
   cb(null, uniqueSuffix + extension);
 }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
// Route handling function
const uploadFoodItem = async (req, res) => {
 try {
   const formData = req.body;
   // Create a new food item document
   const newFoodItem = new global.food_items({
     CategoryName: formData.CategoryName,
     name: formData.name,
     img: req.file.filename, // Store the generated file name in the "img" field
     options: [{ medium: formData.price1, large: formData.price2 }],
     description: formData.description
   });
   const savedFoodItem = await newFoodItem.save();
   console.log('Food item saved:', savedFoodItem);
   res.status(200).json({ message: 'Food item saved successfully' });
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('Error saving food item:', error);
   res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to save food item' });
 }
};
// Route definition
router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), uploadFoodItem);

module.exports = router;
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const pass = 'mongodb+srv://Admin:Admin0202@cluster0.ydoby6v.mongodb.net/mern_website_burger_bro';
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
    await mongoose.connect(pass);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully!');
    const foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      CategoryName: String,
      name: String,
      img: String,
      options: [{
        medium: String,
        large: String,
      }],
      description: String
    });
    const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      CategoryName: String,
    });
    const Food = mongoose.model('food_items', foodSchema);
    module.exports = Food;
    
    const Category = mongoose.model('food_categories', categorySchema);
    try {
      const foodItems = await Food.find({});
      global.food_items = foodItems;
      // console.log(global.food_items);
    } catch (foodError) {
      console.log('Error fetching food items:', foodError);
    }
    try {
      const categories = await Category.find({});
      global.food_category = categories;
      // console.log(global.food_category);
    } catch (categoryError) {
      console.log('Error fetching food categories:', categoryError);  }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('MongoDB connection error:', error);}
};

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

how can i input data on food_item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To give you some information that might help you

1. Please share the tech stack
   For example, if you provide the version information such as the node you are using and the framework, it is easy to identify the issue of that version.

(Packages, etc. are often produced and distributed in the community, and this does not guarantee enterprise-level integrity.)

2. Implement your problem
   Get advice by implementing the problem with a similar online tool from Stackblitz
   Testing by replicating an environment similar to your project can be of great help in solving the problem.

There are various factors for the error you have provided, but in summary, it is as follows.

The busboy library is a widely used library in Node.js to process file uploads and multi-part form data. The "Boundary not found" error usually occurs when the Content-Type header of the HTTP request does not contain or is incorrectly specified.

If you share the results after debugging, the community can infer more solutions to the problem.